# Replace two strings without overriding the other value

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an assignment for school due at midnight today. I have finished almost all the assignment except for one question. I need to swap "r" and "q" with each other as values. So, if you enter "r" in the compiler you should get "q" if you enter "q" you get "r"(Using `JOptionPane`). For example, if your name is Quart, the compiler should print Ruaqt. I tried using the replace.All method, but once I can only swap "r" or "q" not both. I know I need a temporary variable, but do not know anything else...

We had to replace vowels with the letter after them so I did this:

```
String firstName = JOptionPane
    .showInputDialog("What is your first name?");

String lastName = JOptionPane
    .showInputDialog("What is your last name?");

String fullname = firstname + lastname; 
String lowername = fullName.toLowerCase();
String encryptedname = lowername.replaceAll("a", "b")
        .replaceAll("e", "f").replaceAll("i", "j").replaceAll("o", "p")
        .replaceAll("u", "v");
```

Thanks

Comment: You won't get any help on homework assignments if you don't show any attempt or any code.

Comment: You need to loop through the characters, one at a time.

Comment: Could you add this to the question to make it more visible?

Comment: Don't post code in a comment. Edit the question.

Comment: Remember that Java strings and characters are case-sensitive. Also, your code doesn't contain all the combinations for `replaceAll` which you mention in the question (e.g. `Q`->`R`).

Comment: Yes, I need help with replacing the q-->r I tried writing replaceAll("q","r").replaceAll("r","q"); but it only replaces r with q and not q with r

Comment: You cannot use chained calls to `replaceAll` is your case (because there's a circular dependency). You need to loop through the string as Andreas suggests and shift each character. There's a Caesar cipher implementation at [Rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher#Java) which you can use for help if everything else fails.

Comment: Hint: You might want to use char[] fName = fullName.toCharArray();

Answer (score 1):

Dunno why the 2 answers using `StringBuilder` are both making the thing more complicated than needed.

Here is the way you can use `StringBuilder` to do that single character swap:

```
public static String swapChar(String string, char c1, char c2) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string);
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); ++i) {
        if (sb.charAt(i) == c1) {
           sb.setCharAt(i, c2);
        } else if (sb.charAt(i) == c2) {
           sb.setCharAt(i, c1);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

---

Update :

Just found that what you are looking for is actually doing a bunch of replace of character at the same time.  That can be cleanly done by providing a Map as parameter:

```
public static String replaceChars(String string, Map<Character,Character> cmap) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string);
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); ++i) {
        if (cmap.containsKey(sb.charAt(i)) {
            sb.setCharAt(i, cmap.get(sb.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

to use it:

```
// or make a util method to make these even easier to create
Map<Character,Character> cmap = new HashMap<Character,Character>();
cmap.put('r','q');
cmap.put('q','r');
cmap.put('a','b');
cmap.put('e','f');
cmap.put('i','j');
cmap.put('o','p');
cmap.put('u','v');
```

and simply do a replace:

```
String result = replaceChars(inputString, cmap);
```

or even simpler, by making use of Apache Commons Lang:

```
String result = StringUtils.replaceChars(inputString, "rqaeiou", "qrbfjpv");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
private static final char Q_STR = 'q';
private static final char R_STR = 'r';


public static String replaceString(String original, int position, char strToReplace) {
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(original);
    if (strToReplace == Q_STR) {
        strBuilder.setCharAt(position, R_STR);
    } else if (strToReplace == R_STR){
        strBuilder.setCharAt(position, Q_STR);
    }
    return strBuilder.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String firstname = "Quart";
    String lastname = " QuartLastName";

    String fullname = firstname + lastname; 
    String lowername = fullname.toLowerCase();

    //get all chars in String
    char[] array = lowername.toCharArray();

    //list to keep original position of Q char
    List<Integer> allQPosition = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //list to keep original position of R char
    List<Integer> allRPosition = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] == 'q') {
            allQPosition.add(i);
        } else if(array[i] == 'r') {
            allRPosition.add(i);
        }
    }

    //replace q
    for (Integer integer : allQPosition) {
        lowername = replaceString(lowername, integer, Q_STR);
    }

    //replace r
    for (Integer integer : allRPosition) {
        lowername = replaceString(lowername, integer, R_STR);
    }

    //replace others
    String encryptedname = lowername.replace("a", "b")
                                    .replace("e", "f")
                                    .replace("i", "j")
                                    .replace("o", "p")
                                    .replace("u", "v");

    System.out.println("Result: " + encryptedname);
}
```

My solution is:

- Keep all position of 'q' and 'r' from original String.
- Replace each of them
- Replace the rest of other chars

Hope this help

Comment: 1) is there any reason to do it with such complicated "save-positions-and-replace-with-saved-position" approach instead of replacing them directly?  2) your usage of `StringBuilder` is actually a good example on "***how to misuse `StringBuilder`***". You create one `StringBuilder` for every character replacement.  Total waste of resources.  `StringBuilder` (or `StringBuffer`) aims to be created once and let you do miscellaneous change in its content, and then let you transform back to an immutable String at the very end.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. 1) That is the simple way can resolve the question "Replace two strings without overriding the other value". 2) you are right. It's better to use StringBuilder as a parameter in replaceString method.

Comment: 1) Coz you are already iterating through the String char-by-char, replacing it in-place will already work.  2) Actually you don't need replaceString method.  That's what `StringBuilder.setCharAt()` is for

Comment: @Adrian: got it... Thanks so much for the comments. Just add one point for you! :)

Answer (score -2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String origin = "r and q";
    System.out.println(newReplacement(origin, 'r', 'q'));
}

private static String newReplacement(String origin, char firstChar, char secondChar) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer(origin);
    for(int i = 0; i < origin.length(); i++) {
        if(origin.charAt(i) == firstChar) {
            stringBuffer.replace(i, i+1, secondChar + "");
            continue;
        }
        if(origin.charAt(i) == secondChar) {
            stringBuffer.replace(i, i+1, firstChar + "");
        }
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

Rewrite replace method with simple one.

Comment: -1 because: 1. you make a method to supply 2 char, but in your method you are hardcoding to compare with `'q'`.  2. It can be better wrote using a `else if ` but you wrote using a `continue` which makes code harder to trace

Comment: 1, ok, forgot, edited, 2. i knew continue statement is not good, but if using else-if, you have to write else statement in the end( for coding convention) like if -> else if -> else

Comment: 2. Never heard of "making else madatory is a good convention".  Even you want, having an `else` with empty body and comment saying that the character is skipped is still way better having a `continue`. like what you are doing

Comment: it is doubtless good to have `else` but *mandatory*? I actually see coding convention explicitly saying that never use `continue` unless it is really needed.  Your code is actually a good example why using `continue` is making code hard to maintain.  By glancing the `if`s, it is easy to give impression that every `if` case are going to be evaluated (but it turns out not).  That's why `else if` is created for

Comment: So, you leave else statement empty, and it does nothing?, nope, that's not my preferred way. By the way, @Adrian, in this situation, i guess string input won't be too much and no concurrent tasks, hence i cannot see much different between using StringBuffer and StringBuilder, (sr, cannot add comment above)

Comment: Ok, it starts, no need to have more comments here,

Comment: 1) Well, using String Buffer vs Builder has never been my concern here (your usage of"replace" instead of "charAt" is actually much bigger concern, though I haven't raised) 2) so you said you'd rather use something even harder to read just to get rid of some coding convention you don't like? 3) as long as there are misleading information, I will add comment coz it is the obligation of members in member-maintained site like SO